# how to make two columns editable in the add dialog but not during edits in jqgrid

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

Only WWID column is disabled not both columns are disabled`enter code here` please help me to disable two or more columns

```
colNames: ['UserName','WWID', 'Generic', 'Mac'],
                            colModel: [
                                { name: 'UserName', index: 'UserName', key: true, width: '200', editable: true, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                                { name: 'WWID', index: 'WWID', width: '250' , editable: true, sortable: true,sorttype:'int', align: 'center' },
                                { name: 'Generic', index: 'generic', width:'200', editable: true, sortable: true,sorttype:'text', align: 'center' },
                                { name: 'Mac', index: 'mac', width:'200',  editable: true, sortable: true,sorttype:'int', align: 'center' },
                            ],
...............
});
jQuery("#gridId").jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager',
            { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, excel: true, exceltext: 'Excel', cloneToTop: true },
            { // edit option
              url: "Uploading.ashx", closeAfterEdit: true,afterSubmitCell: function () { $('#gridId').trigger('reloadGrid');},
              beforeShowForm: function (form) { $('#tr_UserName', form).hide(); },
              beforeShowForm: function(form) { $('#tr_WWID', form).hide(); } 
},
{ // add option
              url: "Uploading.ashx", closeAfterAdd: true,
              beforeShowForm: function(form) { $('#tr_UserName', form).show(); },
              beforeShowForm: function (form) { $('#tr_WWID', form).show(); }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery("#gridId").jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager',
    { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, excel: true, exceltext: 'Excel', cloneToTop: true },
    //Edit options
    {
        url: "Uploading.ashx",
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        afterSubmitCell: function () { $('#gridId').trigger('reloadGrid'); },
        beforeShowForm: function (form) { $('#tr_UserName', form).hide(); $('#tr_WWID', form).hide(); }
    },
    //Add options
    {
        url: "Uploading.ashx",
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        beforeShowForm: function(form) { $('#tr_UserName', form).show(); $('#tr_WWID', form).show(); }
    },
    ...
);
```

Comment: Though this might have solved the issue, Kindly add a bit more info as to why the above didn't work and how this would be fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide only one `beforeShowForm` callback which will show/hide both rows. In your case only the last one provided is being used. Your code should be like this:

```
jQuery("#gridId").jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager',
    { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, excel: true, exceltext: 'Excel', cloneToTop: true },
    //Edit options
    {
        url: "Uploading.ashx",
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        afterSubmitCell: function () { $('#gridId').trigger('reloadGrid'); },
        beforeShowForm: function (form) { $('#tr_UserName', form).hide(); $('#tr_WWID', form).hide(); }
    },
    //Add options
    {
        url: "Uploading.ashx",
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        beforeShowForm: function(form) { $('#tr_UserName', form).show(); $('#tr_WWID', form).show(); }
    },
    ...
);
```